# Dell E5450 laptops will not recognize any internal HDD

Tags: hard-drive, laptop, bios

I have updated the BIOS, defaulted the settings in the BIOS. I have also changed out the MB for a new one along with the proprietary SATA connection. We have tested out parts from a fully functional e5450 but with no results. I even tried powering down the system by disconnecting the battery and the power supply and holding down start for a while. We have also taken it apart and put it back together again just to make sure nothing was amiss. We are out of options that we know of outside of shipping it back to the warranty people and let them have a try at it. This is not the first time this issue has occurred and the last issue was resolved by shipping it off, having them fix it without telling us how they did it.

Comment: This sounds like you have a hardware issue, probably a disk controller failure. Since it's a laptop, it's likely that the only option will be to replace the system board, and if the computer is still under warranty, contacting the manufacturer or warranty service organization is probably your best recourse.

Comment: System board was replace as mentioned above, so was the cable. I also used a known good HDD. And as I said I am likely sending it back to the company as it is under warranty. I want to learn why so I can get a handle on this next time.

Comment: I suspect that without having the warranty service company's diagnostic tools and service manuals, you're not going to find out what's going on; certainly, your described steps are what I would have done as part of my attempt at diagnosing and remedying the issue. Do note that you're likely to be getting refurbished parts, not factory-fresh ones, and if there was a design or manufacturing defect, repeat instances of the problem are not unlikely. I would recommend that you ensure that you keep good, detailed records of each time this occurs, and the steps you take; this may be relevant later.